# JUnit Test for expected exception fails despite throwing the same exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I've scoured through StackOverflow for the same types of questions, and checked each response, but still facing this problem. I am testing for a **IOException** to be thrown from a method called **readStream()**, and the method does throw the **IOException**, but Junit fails the test with an **AssertionException**.

```
private static StringBuilder readStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    String line;

    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
   finally {
        try{
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder;
}
```

Here is my unit test:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = RequestResponseUtility.class)
public class RequestResponseUtilityTest extends AbstractTest {

    @Mock
    private InputStream inputStream;

    @Test(expected = IOException.class)
    public void convertStreamToStringNullTest() throws IOException {

        RequestResponseUtility.convertStreamToString(inputStream);
    }
}
```

I've tried, as you see, to have the exception in the original class actually throw the exception, rather than just catch and print the stack trace:

```
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
```

I've also tried both using the annotation **@Test(expected=IOException.class)** and using the @Rule approach. Both fail the test. I've tried annotating my test with both **@SpringBootTest** (as you see above) and with **@RunWith(springjunit4classrunner.class)**. I'm really at a loss here. I get this error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.io.IOException
```

But my stack trace is

```
java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:288)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at main.java.utilities.RequestResponseUtility.readStream(RequestResponseUtility.java:25)
    at main.java.utilities.RequestResponseUtility.convertStreamToString(RequestResponseUtility.java:45)
```

This is breaking my heart. It's not a huge deal and doesn't impact the performance of my code in production, but I want to understand why it's actually happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I feel kind of silly because I just solved my own question right after I posted this. I didn't examine the stack trace closely enough:

```
at main.java.utilities.RequestResponseUtility.readStream(RequestResponseUtility.java:25)
        at main.java.utilities.RequestResponseUtility.convertStreamToString(RequestResponseUtility.java:45)
        at test.java.utilities.RequestResponseUtilityTest.convertStreamToStringNullTest(RequestResponseUtilityTest.java:42)
```

The first method that is called is **convertStreamToStringNullTest()**, my unit test. This calls **convertStreamToString()**. However, **convertStreamToString()** actually calls a private helper method inside my **RequestResponseUtilit**y class called **readStream()**. In my question, I had posted the code to **readStream()**, since I knew intuitively that was where the exception was being thrown.

However, as the exception propagates back down the stack to **convertStreamToString()**, I never throw the exception. I only print the stack trace. So it gets stuck at that method, and therefore the unit test, which is "listening" for a **IOException** from **convertStreamToString()**, never gets the thrown exception!

Moral of the story is to check for nested methods and really trace where your exception should be coming from!